# How to use a library only if it was enabled in configure script

Tags: c, makefile

I want to use a library in my code if and only if it was enabled in the configure script.
The user will compile the program by first running the configure script and then make

```
./configure --enable-mylib
make
```

And I need that this `--enable-mylib`
becomes a boolean and a define in my code so that I can use it as for example

```
#ifdef MYLIB
#include "mylib.h"
#endif
...
if(mylib_enabled()) {
  do_mylib_call();
}
...
```

What is the standard way of doing so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your check for the `--enable-mylib` you should check for the library, and if found you will have an `HAVE_MYLIB` macro that you can check for.

Something like this in your configure script:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE([mylib],
  [  --enable-mylib          enable the special "mylib" library],
  [if test $enableval = yes; then
     AC_CHECK_LIB(mylib, function_in_mylib)
     AC_CHECK_HEADER(mylib.h)
   fi])
```

And this in your source file

```
#if HAVE_MYLIB_H
# include <mylib.h>
#endif

...

#if HAVE_MYLIB
function_in_mylib();
#endif
```

Comment: What are the advantages of this compared to passing the -DHAVE_MYLIB flag to gcc ?

Comment: @anotherCode245 Because it actually *check* that the library and its header file exists. If you just check the enable-flag, and set the `HAVE_MYLIB` unconditionally, what would happen on systems that doesn't have the library?

Comment: I understand. In fact my enable flag is ```--enable-mylib=<absolute-path-to-mylib>``` so the responsability is more on the user to provide correctly the library but I don't know if it's very good. (the library is not a standard one you would find in package managers)